# drawing image laggy on iPhone plus

Tags: ios, iphone, drawing, lag

I want to draw lines on a view, here's my code.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [self.image drawInRect:self.bounds];
}

- (void)drawNewLine {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    [self.image drawInRect:self.bounds];

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0.51, 0.85, 0.81, 1);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 4.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);

    CGPoint mid1 = midPoint(previousPoint1, previousPoint2);
    CGPoint mid2 = midPoint(currentPoint, previousPoint1);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, mid1.x, mid1.y);
    CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(ctx, previousPoint1.x, previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y);

    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [recognizer resetTouches];
    [recognizer addTouches:touches fromView:self];
    self.image = nil;
    previousPoint1 = previousPoint2 = currentPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    previousPoint2 = previousPoint1;
    previousPoint1 = currentPoint;
    currentPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    [self drawNewLine];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self drawNewLine];
    [self processGestureData];
}
```

It worked fine on other devices except iPhone plus, on 6/6s/7 plus, you can see the clear lag. Can someone please tell me where I did wrong. Thanks a lot.

Here's my app. [CallHoney](https://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/callhoney/id1241846219?l=en&mt=8)

Comment: Use Time Profiler to look for slow sections in your code and optimise them.

Comment: It's an odd design, wouldn't you use the touch methods to accumulate an array of points, calling setNeedsDisplay whenever a point is added?  On touchesEnd, you would then do the (what is probably a much more expensive) operation of allocating a new graphics context, drawing to it, copying out the contents as an image representation, drawing that image into the view?